# Setting up Search in the Toolbar Support Action Bar doesn't work why?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to add/create a Search functionality for my app! So after passing android documentation there was training on how to do that! I added it as it was explained but It doesn't work when I click on the search icon It doesn't respond and I can't even put any text to be searched! I am using support version 25.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

              <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
              android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar" />

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
              android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="60dp"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs_three"
              app:bb_behavior="shy"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a struggle I realized,the error was caused of wrapping of Views in the Coordinator Layout. So the clicking of Toolbar was not felt it was taken up by other Views added after it. So I could change layout attributes but I decided to use Relative Layout instead.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar" />

            <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
                android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_bar_tabs" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the query listener. It detects any input that was made in the searchview

```
SearchView simpleSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.simpleSearchView);
            simpleSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    //searchedInput will be the text that was entered
                    String searchedInput = query;
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: It doesn't work!The issue is that I cant add any information/text/words to the input field because the input field doesn't appear on the icon click or touch! QueryListener!